# touches moved on image view is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimageview

This is the image which shows what is happening on my touches moved:

[image]

Touches moved on ui image view, but it is not working properly.

Comment: In viewDidLoad put [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
as UIImageView by default not intractable.

Comment: Try using UIPanGestureRecognizer